# Using AJAX/PHP/mysqli to create a load more button

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

In my code below I am trying to create a load more button using AJAX. I have `main.php` which includes PHP code for calling blogs from database initially, some jQuery code and a load more button. Then I have `ajax_more.php` which calls more data from database when load more is clicked. Load more buttons are displayed perfectly and when clicked they change to loading and then disappear. Nothing else happens and `main.php` still shows those two initial blogs which we call first. Please look into code and help where this code has gone wrong.

**main.php**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click', '.show_more', function () {
            var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.show_more').hide();
            $('.loding').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax_more.php',
                data: 'id=' + ID,
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#show_more_main' + ID).remove();
                    $('.columns').append(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<?php
$query = "
    SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category
    FROM blogs 
        INNER JOIN categories 
            ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id 
    WHERE category='cat1' OR category='catt2' OR category='cat3' OR category='cat4' 
    ORDER BY blogs_id desc 
    LIMIT 2
";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($rowCount > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $blogs_id = $row['blogs_id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $body = $row['body'];
        $posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
        $full_name = $row['full_name'];
        $bio = $row['bio'];
        $posted = $row['posted'];

        echo "
            <div class='db'>
                <h2>$title</h2>
                <p>$body</p>
                <p>$bio</p>
            </div>
        ";
?>
<div class="show_more_main" id="show_more_main<?php echo $blogs_id; ?>">
    <span id="<?php echo $blogs_id; ?>" class="show_more" title="Load more posts">Show more</span>
    <span class="loding" style="display: none;"><span class="loding_txt">Loading…</span></span>
</div>
```

**ajax_more.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["blogs_id"]) && !empty($_POST["blogs_id"])) {
    $query = "
        SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category 
        FROM blogs 
            INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id 
        WHERE category='Entertainment' OR category='Politics' OR category='Sports' OR category='Travel'
            AND blogs_id < ".$_POST['blogs_id']." 
        ORDER BY blogs_id DESC 
        LIMIT 2
    ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $blogs_id = $row['blogs_id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $body = $row['body'];
            $posted_by = $row['posted_by'];
            $full_name = $row['full_name'];
            $bio = $row['bio'];
            $posted = $row['posted'];

            echo "
                <div class='db'>
                <h2>$title</h2>
                <p>$body</p>
                <p>$bio</p>
                </div>
            ";
?>
```

Comment: Where is the columns element?

Comment: code for calling initial blogs itself is placed in columns but due to large style sheet i didn't add it here, i guess it's not the problem.

Comment: `main.php` line 15, did not close your success function. (It also helps to check your browser console for any errors)

Comment: @FranklinSatler "**This is why PHP is known as a bad language**" Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your query to this

```
$query = "SELECT blogs_id, title, body, posted_by, full_name, bio, posted, category FROM
 blogs INNER JOIN categories ON categories.category_id=blogs.category_id WHERE
(category='Entertainment' OR category='Politics' OR category='Sports' OR category='Travel') 
 AND blogs_id < " . $_POST['blogs_id'] . " ORDER BY blogs_id DESC LIMIT 2";
```

All the OR's must be enclosed in the brackets....

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below technique to load more data with just replacing morebox html.

### blog.php

```
<div class="tutorial_list">
   <!-- LOAD YOUR PHP BLOG DATA -->
   <div class="loading"><img src="fb-load.gif"/></div>
   <!-- More Button here $ID values is a last post id value. -->
   <div id="show_more<?php echo $ID; ?>" class="morebox">
      <a href="#" class="show_more" id="<?php echo $ID; ?>">more</a>
   </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.show_more', function() {
  {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    if (ID) {
        $('.morebox').hide();
        $('.loding').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_more.php",
            data: "lastpost=" + ID,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.loading').hide();
                $('.tutorial_list').append(html);
                $("#show_more" + ID).remove(); // removing old more button
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".morebox").html('The End'); // no results
    }
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

### ajax_more.php

```
<!-- LOAD YOUR PHP BLOG DATA WITH lastpost ID and remember to add below code for load more -->

<!-- More Button here $ID values is a last post id value. -->
<div id="show_more<?php echo $ID; ?>" class="morebox">
    <a href="#" class="show_more" id="<?php echo $ID; ?>">more</a>
</div>
```